# Prove if $L = K(α_1, . . . , α_r)$ and each $\alpha_i$ is separable over $K$, then $L/K$ is separable

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

> Let $L/K$ be a finite extension, $[L:K] = n$.
>
> Prove the following are equivalent:
>
> 1. $L/K$ is separable
> 2. $L=K(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n)$ and every $\alpha_i$ is separable over $K$.

I understand the part where $(1\ \implies 2)$, can anyone please explain to me the other direction $(2 \Longleftarrow 1)$?

Comment: What characterizations of separability do you know? Of course it's fine to ask here, but maybe it helps to point out that this is certainly in Lang's _Algebra_ and probably other standard references such as Artin's _Galois Theory_.

Answer (score 1):

**Claim 1:** Let $\alpha$ be algebraic over $K$. $K(\alpha)/K$ is separable if, and only if, $\alpha$ is separable over $K$.

**Proof:** (idea) As $\alpha$ is algebraic over $K$ we may take $p_{\alpha} (x)$ irreducible polynomial such that $p_{\alpha} (\alpha) =0$. Notice that $K(\alpha) / K$ has degree $n = \partial p_{\alpha}$ and $[K(\alpha):K]_s$ is the number of distinct roots of $p_u(x)$ (look at the closure if necessary). Those numbers are the same if, and only if, $p_u(x)$ is separable. If $p_{\alpha}(x)$ is irreducible then $p'_{\alpha}(x) \neq 0$ then is separable.

**Claim 2:** Let $\alpha_1, \ldots , \alpha_n$ be algebraic over $K$.

$K(\alpha_1, \ldots , \alpha_n)/K$
 is separable if, and only if, $\alpha_1, \ldots , \alpha_n$ are separable over $K$.

**Proof:** Assuming $\alpha_1, \ldots , \alpha_n$ are separable over $K$ we will use induction over $n$.

- $n=1$ See Claim 1;
- Considering the assertion true to $n-1$ and the tower

$$K \subseteq K(\alpha_1, \ldots , \alpha_{n-1},\alpha_n) \subseteq K(\alpha_1, \ldots , \alpha_{n-1})(\alpha_n)$$

it follows that $K(\alpha_1, \ldots , \alpha_{n-1})/K$ is separable by induction hypothesis. Now $\alpha_n$ is separable over $K$ hence is it is also separable over $K(\alpha_1, \ldots , \alpha_{n-1})$ (look at the minimal polynomial over the larger field). By Claim 1 we see that $$K(\alpha_1, \ldots , \alpha_{n-1}, \alpha_n)/K(\alpha_1, \ldots , \alpha_{n-1})$$

is separable, then $K(\alpha_1, \ldots , \alpha_n)/K$ is separable.

Comment: $[K(\alpha):K]_s$ is the separability degree of $K(\alpha)/K$?

Comment: Yes, it is. Just a way to write it.